# python Condition wait and notify_all

Tags: python, multithreading, conditional-statements

I am trying to run the Synchronizing Operations demo [here](http://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html#synchronizing-operations) , the expected result is:

```
Starting s1
s1 done and ready for stage 2
Starting stage_2[1]
stage_2[1] running
Starting stage_2[2]
stage_2[2] running
```

But sometime I got this :

```
Starting stage_2[2]
stage_2[2] running
Starting stage_2[1]
stage_2[1] running
Starting s1
s1 done and ready for stage 2
```

I am using Python 2.7.3 and windows. Anyone have idea why stage 2s are executed before stage1?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the multiprocessing documentation whether it does something special to avoid spurious wakeups, but in general calling `cond.wait()` without a conditional loop is problematic.

If that's the problem, something like this

```
def stage_2(cond):
    """wait for the condition telling us stage_1 is done"""
    name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    print 'Starting', name
    with cond:
        while stage < 2:
            cond.wait()
        print '%s running' % name
```

would fix it. Here `stage` would really have to be a ctypes object created with multiprocessing.Value(), or something similar.